# Figure and Table pretext in LOF and LOT

Tags: table-of-contents

I have Algorithms, Figures and Tables in my project and in the list of Algorithms, all the algorithms are listed with the user-defined Pretext 'Algorithm'.  I don't know how to define similar pretexts for Tables and Figures.  Currently the file takes the same pretext 'Algorithm' for all components as shown in the below MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
    {
    \let\oldnumberline\numberline
    \renewcommand{\numberline}{Algorithm~\oldnumberline}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listalgorithmname}
    \listofalgorithms
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
    \listoffigures
    }
    \begin{figure}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=9cm]{example-image-a}
      \caption{Example Image}
      \label{fig:example}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{algorithm}
    \caption{MHCM}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \If{condition}
            \State do something
        \Else
            \State do something else
        \EndIf
    \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The tocloft package can probably handle it.

Comment: @daleif The `tocloft` package CAN handle it.